# How to localize two variables for a subsequent call to a predefined subroutine?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to emulate the `reduce` function from `List::Util`.

The problem I'm having is that the subroutine reference passed to my `reducer`
is unable to access the lexical `$a` and `$b` variables.

I've tried declaring them
in the `reduce` subroutine with both `my` and `local`, but neither worked.

My current subroutine is this, with (for testing) `our $DEBUG = 1;`
at the top of the file:

```perl
sub reduce(&@) {
    my $code = shift;

    if ( @_ == 0 ) {
        print "No items passed to reduce, returning undef\n" if $DEBUG;
        return undef;
    }

    if ( @_ == 1 ) {
        print "One item passed to reduce, returning it\n" if $DEBUG;
        return shift;
    }

    my $a = shift;    # Also tried "local $a = shift;"
    my $b = shift;    # Also tried "local $b = shift;"

    print "Starting reduction loop with a = [$a] and b = [$b]\n" if $DEBUG;

    while ( @_ ) {
        $a = $code->();
        $b = shift;
        print "- Reductive iteration ended with a = [$a] and b = [$b]\n" if $DEBUG;
    }

    my $val = &{$code};

    print "- Finished reductive loop with value [$val]\n" if $DEBUG;

    return $val;
}
```

And I'm calling it as

```perl
print "" . (reduce { print "-- $a + $b\n"; $a + $b; } 1..10) . "\n";
```

My output is this:

```
Starting reduction loop with a = [0] and b = [1]
--  + 
- Reductive iteration ended with a = [0] and b = [2]
--  + 
- Reductive iteration ended with a = [0] and b = [3]
--  + 
- Reductive iteration ended with a = [0] and b = [4]
--  + 
- Reductive iteration ended with a = [0] and b = [5]
--  + 
- Reductive iteration ended with a = [0] and b = [6]
--  + 
- Reductive iteration ended with a = [0] and b = [7]
--  + 
- Reductive iteration ended with a = [0] and b = [8]
--  + 
- Reductive iteration ended with a = [0] and b = [9]
--  + 
- Reductive iteration ended with a = [0] and b = [10]
--  + 
- Finished reductive loop with value [0]
0
```

How do I get the subroutine reference passed to `reduce` to see `$a` and `$b`?

Comment: @toolic: `$a` and `$b` are reserved for precisely this sort of use, but this will misbehave in the same way with any pair of variables that you nominate. `$a` and `$b` are reserved only so that any called subroutines or asynchronous activity that calls `sort` or `List::Util::reduce` or similar won't affect the main code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [another pure perl reduce implementation](https://metacpan.org/source/PERLANCAR/PERLANCAR-List-Util-PP-0.04/lib/PERLANCAR/List/Util/PP.pm#L236). The key insight is that `$a` and `$b` in the sub you pass to `reduce` are global variables in the calling package namespace, and inside the `reduce` implementation you perform a little symbol table wizardry to obtain them. I have changed the lexical variable names here (to `$aa` and `$bb`) to distinguish them from `$a` and `$b` in the caller:

```
sub reduce (&@) {
  my $f = shift;
  ...
  my $pkg = caller;
  my $aa = shift;               # first element in list (after function spec)

  no strict 'refs';
  # makes '$a' in calling package an alias for local '$aa'
  local *{"${pkg}::a"} = \$aa;

  # $glob_b is a reference to stash for `b` in calling package   
  my $glob_b = \*{"${pkg}::b"};

  foreach my $bb (@_) {
    # $glob_b is reference to stash for caller's 'b'
    # *$glob_b is the stash for caller's 'b'
    # assigning scalar reference to *$glob_b updates '$b' in calling pkg
    local *$glob_b = \$bb;

    # $aa is aliased to caller's $a, so $a is updated within this loop
    $aa = $f->();
  }
  $aa;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this leave `$a` and `$b` in the caller's namespace, though?

Comment: Yes, and when you call `$code->()` (in OP) or `$f->()` (in this answer), it executes the code in the calling namespace.

Comment: We need `no strict 'refs'` for `"${pkg}::a`, yes?

Comment: Yes. The rest of the code I linked to starts with `use strict 'vars','subs'`.

Comment: Ah, I see.  But your posted code (w/o `...`) works with just that added -- why not add it?  I'm not complaining -- this is great :)  I just learned how to do it, thank you :)

Comment: I meant, doesn't that leave `$a` and `$b` in the caller's namespace after the call to `reduce` is finished? Or is that what the `local`s are for?

Comment: Yes, with `local`, the `$a` and `$b` vars in the calling package are restored when the `reduce` function is finished.

Comment: @mob: That is what `CORE::sort` does. Code like `dd [$a, $b ]; dd [ sort reverse 'a' .. 'z' ]; dd [$a, $b ];` produces `[undef, undef] ["a" .. "z"] [undef, undef]`.

Answer (score 1):

It's best not to guess about how to pass values. If you really have no idea what to do after reading the documentation then messing with `my` and `local` will just get you more confused. Both of those ideas will make sure that those variables are discarded at the end of the current block of code, but because `local` works with *package variables*, any call to the passed subroutine reference will be able to see those temporary values

You don't define a real purpose for calling `reduce` so I have written something which just concatenates all of the values in the list and returns the result. Please always provide something that we can test and fix

Here's a working `my_reduce`. Note that the real `reduce` must examine the namespace of the calling code and modify `$a` and `$b` in *that* package. Here, I've simply put `my_reduce` in the same package as the calling code

I have also used `List::Util::reduce` in parallel to make sure that the two results agree

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use List::Util ();

my $DEBUG = 1;

sub my_reduce(&@);

my @abc = 'a' .. 'z';

say List::Util::reduce(
    sub { $a . $b },
    @abc
);

say my_reduce(
    sub { $a . $b },
    @abc
);

sub my_reduce(&@) {
    my $code = shift;

    if ( @_ == 0 ) {
        print "No items passed to reduce, returning undef\n" if $DEBUG;
        return undef;
    }
    elsif ( @_ == 1 ) {
        print "One item passed to reduce, returning it.\n" if $DEBUG;
        return shift;
    }
    else {
        while ( @_ > 1 ) {
            local ($a, $b) = splice @_, 0, 2;
            unshift @_, $code->();
        }
        return shift;
    }
}
```

#### output

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: Your `my_reduce` is setting `$a` and `$b` in the main package, and it won't work if you call it from a different package. e.g., add `package NotMain; say main::my_reduce(sub{$a.$b},'a'..'z');` to the end of your script.

Comment: @mob: Yeah I just wrote about that. But it's the same scenario as the OP's code.